# Why do I still get xAMP errors after fixing my PHP code and saving the file?

Tags: php, apache

This question applies to several types of coding errors, from leaving dollar signs off the front of PHP variables to forgetting to put a semicolon between statements, to leaving unmatched braces and quotation marks. I make lots of stupid typos that result in errors.

When I read the apache error log to find out what I did wrong, then go back and fix the errors, and save the file and reload the page to see if it works, sometimes I have to restart apache to get the new code to execute.

For example, if  I write "SEELCT * FROM MyTable", try to load the page, get an error, correct the SQL to "SELECT * FROM MyTable", save the file and refresh the page in my browser, sometimes my error-handling code will still show the typo in the old SQL statement. After I restart Apache, everything works fine.

Is there a PHP or Apache setting that would allow me to get the correct results as soon as I fix my code and save it?

Comment: if your 'error view' is provided by a browser, you may want to clear cache.

Comment: Disabling my Firefox browser cache doesn't appear to have any effect on this issue.

Comment: Maybe it's the server that's doing the caching then. the fact it works after restarting Apache may lend some weight to that theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to disable opcache. Open your php.ini (Xampp control panel -> first config button -> php.ini) and find the line contain opcache.enable= and change its value to 0. If it is not, add new line:

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Then restart apache only 1 more time.
You could also try to clear the browser cache after all.

Comment: That did it, thanks very much! For the record, I am using Bitnami Mediawiki 1.34.1-0 WAMP stack and the setting was on line 1792 of PHP.ini